# how can i go about reseting the inital view of my tab?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Wondering how i could go about reseting the initial view of the tab once another tab is selected and if you go back to the tab i would like it to be reset to the first view every time.

If you can help me with any guidance on this topic would help me a lot, googled this topic a lot and tried implementing stuff around the internet but nothing really helped.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function on the view controller to reset the UI (reset label values, clear text ares, etc) whatever you need to do to get the view back to its initial state then in the delegate method didSelectViewController on you UITabBarController delegate call the reset method. You may want to sub class UiViewControll and add in the reset method and then make all of your controllers a subclass of that. You could also just add the reset code in the viewWillAppear method and call that from the didSelectViewController method, that way the code will be executed on first load and when it is re displayed by the tab bar.

Comment: You could also just add the reset code in the viewWillAppear method and call that from the didSelectViewController method, that way the code will be executed on first load and when it is re displayed by the tab bar.

Comment: I suggest you update your answer with the suggestion to use viewDidLoad